# Как сделать рандомное исчезнование и соударения в системе частиц

Tags: javascript, canvas

Сделал простенькую систему частиц.

- Как сделать соударение между частицами?
- Как сделать рандомное исчезновение и появление частиц?

  ```
  var ctx, w, h, canvas;
      var point = [];
      var N = 2000;

  function rand(min, max) {
      return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
      }

  window.onload = function() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  w = canvas.width;
  h = canvas.height;
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, w, h);
  init();
   }
  function init() {
     for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        point[i] = new stat(rand(0, w), h / 2, rand(.01, .5) - rand(.01,.5), rand(.01, .5) - rand(.01, .5));
  }

  setInterval(draw, 33);
  }

  function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {

          ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(point[i].x, point[i].y, 1, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
      point[i].x += point[i].vx;
      point[i].y += point[i].vy;
      if (point[i].x > w - .5 ) {
          point[i].vx = -point[i].vx;
      }
      if (point[i].y > h - .5) {
           point[i].vy = -point[i].vy;
      }
      if (point[i].x < 0) {
          point[i].vx = -point[i].vx;
      }
      if (point[i].y < .5) {
          point[i].vy = -point[i].vy;
      }


      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
  }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

С появлением и исчезновением нет ни чего сложного.
По альфе делаете заливку прозрачной, перебрасываете объект резко на другую позицию.
Либо удаляете и создаете новый.

А вот столкновения это не так легко, можно обложиться матаном и рассчитывать столкновения.
Я рекомендую посмотреть в сторону готовых решений - [одно из известных мне](http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/index2.html)